# Python, How to get an image from a Buffer/stream

Tags: python, stream, buffer

I've been trying to use an API that sends a json and their image key holds an array with int buffers, the buffers are of NodeJS's buffer streams, how to do get the image out of it in python? I've did google and found other questions of them in stackoverflow but i didn't understand them and some didn't help, i hope someone knows, let me know in comments if you have any questions.

To help more, the data looks like this

```
[82, 232, 68, 55, 218]
```

Just a sample, the original one goes over thousand lines or something.

Comment: What are the first 20 items or so of one of image arrays?

Comment: Basically as example i sent, bunch of numbers elements.

Comment: Yes, but **what numbers**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with bytes() method I'll just leave this if someone else needs it, bytes would give bytes object i needed that i can use to write to image file etc.